# Using SSIS to Export Data from SQL Server to Oracle CRM On-Demand

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, crm

My company has signed on with Oracle CRM On-Demand, and without debating the merits of the application, I wanted to find out if anyone in the SO community is using SSIS to import data from SQL Server through the CRMOD web service.

If so, how is the experience been in maintaining it over time and have you gone through any pains in dealing with the web service calls?

My hope is to be able to have scheduled jobs take updated information from our DW in SQL Server over to CRMOD and have started tinkering around with it, but if anyone's already solved the problem and willing to share some details, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved my own issue.  Basically, I took exports of data from my SQL DB, loaded them into CSV files and looped through those files with a batch command and mapping file that CRMOD generates through the java based CLI data loader.  The CLI loader just builds a web service push and as long as you can plug in your credentials, you're off and running.

Still in the works is the export out from CRMOD to SQL, but that's for another post.